# Problema em requisição JSON - API - json_decode

Tags: php, json, back-end

Saudações, estou tentando fazer uma requisição de um JSON para poder anexar cada valor em uma variável, conduto, estou recebendo os erros:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'produto' of non-object in E:\Rafael\Desktop\T.I\Xamp\htdocs\litoralplace\backend\productshow.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\Rafael\Desktop\T.I\Xamp\htdocs\litoralplace\backend\productshow.php on line 14

Meu código:

```php
<?php
    $json_file = file_get_contents('produtos.json', true);
$codigo; $descricao; $tipo;
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file);
foreach ($json_str->retorno->produtos->produto as $key) {
    $codigo = $key->codigo;
    $descricao = $key->descricao;
    $tipo = $key->tipo;
}
?>
```

infelizmente não posso disponibilizar o arquivo produtos.json pois possui informações confidenciais da empresa. Vou apenas exemplifica-lo:

```js
{
"retorno": {
  "produtos": [
    {
     "produto": {
        "codigo": "1",
        "descricao": "Fonte Thermaltake 430W Smart Séries",
        "tipo": "P"
     },
     "produto": {
        "codigo": "2",
        "descricao": "Processador AMD Ryzen 3 3200G",
        "tipo": "P",
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

No JSON existem 100 Produtos, estou tentando inserir nas variáveis apenas um produto e seus parâmetros. Perdão se ficou um pouco confuso, preciso muito dessa ajuda.

Exemplificando o que preciso:
Necessito pegar os valores de cada Produto (codigo, descrição e tipo), e anexar em um array. Por exemplo: Array de codigos: Precisa ser preenchido com os codigos 1 e 2. A minha dúvida é não saber como diferenciar esses dois "produto" para angariar as informações deles, já que o JSON foi formatado dessa maneira através de uma API.

Comment: Esse json está incorreto

Comment: complicado, ele é fruto de uma API, veio assim já. Como devo corrigi-lo?

Comment: Agora, vi, está com as chaves erradas, vou corrigir. De qualquer maneira, esse erro não está de fato no meu código.

Comment: Dá um `print_r($json_str); die;` e posta o retorno.

Comment: ```php
stdClass Object
(
    [retorno] => stdClass Object
        (
            [produtos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [produto] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [codigo] => 2
                                    [descricao] => Processador AMD Ryzen 3 3200G
                                    [tipo] => P
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```
aqui amigo

Comment: O seu `foreach` é pra ir até `$json_str->retorno->produtos`. `produto` é um item do array de produtos.

Comment: entendi!! Boa, muito obrigado. Contudo, como devo fazer para diferenciar e percorrer os itens indexados cada Produto que está no array produtos?

Comment: Desculpa mas não consegui entender o que você quer fazer, por favor se possível edita a pergunta e tenta exemplificar o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Pode deixar, farei isso. Obrigado

Comment: Editei lá, se puder dar uma olhada, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente você quer criar um `array` só com os códigos dos produtos. Então o código abaixo deve ajudar você a fazer isso.

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('produtos.json', true);
$codigos = [];
$json_str = json_decode($json_file);

foreach ($json_str->retorno->produtos as $value) {
    $codigos[] = $value->produto->codigo;
}

print_r($codigos); die;

// O exemplo irá imprimir
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: Retornou um erro de Propriedade Indefinida: Undefined property: stdClass::$codigo in E:\Rafael\Desktop\T.I\Xamp\htdocs\litoralplace\backend\productshow.php on line 16

$json_file = file_get_contents('contatos.json', true);
$codigos = [];
$json_str = json_decode($json_file);

foreach ($json_str->retorno->produtos as $produto) {
    $codigos[] = $produto->codigo; //linha 16
}

print_r($codigos); die;

Comment: Testa o seguinte: `$produto->produto->codigo`

Comment: agora funcionou, mas retornou somente um item:
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)